# How do I cancel SSIS jobs in Created Execution status

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two SSIS jobs that are stuck in Created Execution status.  They cannot run since the package version has changed (I get Error Msg 27150:     The version of the project has changed since the instance of the execution has been created. Create a new execution instance and try again.) I do not want to run this anymore, just delete it.

How can I remove these from the execution log?  catalog.stop_operation does not work since there is no active operation for this job.

Note: the job does not appear in Active Operations, since it never started.

Comment: This is from memory and just a thought. I think I had this happen while an execution was running and then an unplanned reboot happened. It never would end since it wasn't running anymore. I believe the fix was to add an end date in the table.

Comment: Just tried that, no joy! set both start and end times to getdate(), still appearing as "created execution"

Comment: I have the same problem.  The only thing I can think of is to re-deploy the project version that was used to create the execution and then try to start the execution manually `exec ssisdb.catalog.start_execution @execution_id = XXX`

Answer (score 3):

SSISDB keeps track of all operations that are currently active/executing. In order to retrieve a list of all active operations, you need to right-click SSISDB and choose Active Operations

[image]

You can then click the Stop button located at the bottom right of the window

[image]

It’s also possible to do the same process via T-SQL. You can stop a package by calling the stored procedure catalog.stop_operation passing the operation ID as a parameter

Use this query to retrieve all currently running packages in the SSIS. Catalog and their IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.executions WHERE end_time IS NULL
```

The statement below stops the execution of the SSIS package with operation_id=65

```
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.stop_operation @operation_id =  65
```

Comment: Hmmm, in my case there is an execution id, but no operation for it.  It hasn't started.  So it does not appear in Active Operations.  It shows in executions, but stop_operation does not work since there is no active operation for the execution.

Comment: @user1443098, did you try the 2nd option?

Comment: the one from @keithL?  Yeah, didn't work

Comment: No, I mean the 2nd option I've provided using the stop_operation sp

Comment: AS I mentioned above,"but stop_operation does not work since there is no active operation for the execution."